# Filling a Progress Bar without a button

Tags: python, progress-bar, ttk

so I'm trying to make a progress bar that automatically starts filling when
the window is opened..
so instead of making a button that when pressed it call the function of filling
the bar I call the function directly, and unexpectedly for me it shows an empty
window and after 5 sec (the time to fill the bar) the bar shows filled
the thing is that when I replaced the fill() with a button it works properly
so why isn't it working just by calling the function and how to make it fill
without a button
my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk as ttk
from time import *

def fill():
    t = 100
    x = 0
    s = 1
    while x <= t:
        bar['value'] += s
        x += s
        sleep(0.05)
        window2.update_idletasks()


def read():

    global window2
    window2 = Tk()

    global bar
    bar = ttk.Progressbar(window2,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=300)
    bar.pack(pady=15)

    fill()       # here I replace the function with a button calling it and it works well but I don't want a button

    window2.mainloop()

read()
```

Comment: First you cannot use sleep or while with tkinter. It blocks the mainloop and that is why you do not see any progress until while loop is done. Like many question on this exact problem here the solution will be managing your updates using the tkinter `after()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the use of `time.sleep` in `tkinter`.

Instead use the `after` scheduler.

The following code modification with comments shows one way to implement it.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk as ttk

def fill(s, c):
    c = c + 1
    # Update progressbar
    bar['value'] = c
    # Test for exit conditions
    if c <= s:
        # Repeat action recursively by passing current values back to itself
        window2.after(50, fill, s, c)
    else:
        bar.destroy()
        # Ready to continue creating other widgets

def read():

    global window2
    window2 = Tk()

    global bar

    delay, steps, count = 50, 100, 0

    # Include the maximum step value `steps` for given length
    bar = ttk.Progressbar(window2, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 300, maximum = steps)
    bar.pack(pady=15)
    # Begin by using `after` scheduler with `delay` to pass `steps` and `count` to `fill` function
    window2.after(delay, fill, steps, count)

    window2.mainloop()

read()
```